# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation relative to two non-standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear transformation defined by
>   \begin{align*}
> T\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}2x-y+z\\-x+y+4z\end{bmatrix}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Let $\mathcal{B}_{1}=\{\vec{v}_{1},\vec{v}_{2},\vec{v}_{3}\}$, $\mathcal{B}_{2}=\{\vec{e}_{1},\vec{e}_{2},\vec{e}_{3}\}$, $\mathcal{D}_{1}=\{\vec{w}_{1},\vec{w}_{2}\}$, and $\mathcal{D}_{2}=\{\vec{f}_{1},\vec{f}_{2}\}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \vec{v}_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \vec{v}_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \vec{v}_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}\ \vec{w}_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \vec{w}_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\4\end{bmatrix}.
> \end{align*}
>   Vectors $\vec{e}_{i}$, $\vec{f}_{k}$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$; $\mathcal{B}_{1}$, $\mathcal{B}_{2}$ are bases of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$; and $\mathcal{D}_{1}$, $\mathcal{D}_{2}$ are bases of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
>
> 1. Find $M_{\mathcal{D}_{1}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(T)$, $M_{\mathcal{D}_{1}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{2}}(T)$, $M_{\mathcal{D}_{2}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(T)$, and $M_{\mathcal{D}_{2}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{2}}(T)$
> 2. Verify that $C_{\mathcal{D}_{2}}(T(\vec{x}))=M_{\mathcal{D}_{2}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(T)C_{\mathcal{B}_{1}}(\vec{x})$ for all $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I'm on very shaky ground regarding the process to do this, but after thinking for a while, I'm curious if, for number 1, instead of solving directly for $M_{\mathcal{D}_{1}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(T)$, can I instead try to solve

\begin{align}M_{\mathcal{D}_{1}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(T)&=M_{\mathcal{D}_{1}\leftarrow \mathcal{E}}(id)M_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow \mathcal{E}}(T)M_{\mathcal{E}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}_{1}}(id)\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&1\\-1&1&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

If not, how would I go about this?

Comment: Does the question state that the matrix for $T$ is defined with respect to the standard basis?  That is, is the matrix we're given $M_{\mathcal B_2 \to \mathcal D_2}(T)?$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Unfortunately, all it says is what $T$ is for a given $\langle x,y,z\rangle$.

Comment: Well, I guess that's probably what they mean, then.  Anyway, I think you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming that I am under the right impression (see question in comment above), we can find the matrix $M_{\mathcal B_1 \to \mathcal D_1}$ as
$$
M_{\mathcal B_1 \to \mathcal D_1} = id_{D_2 \to D_1}M_{B_2 \to D_2}(T)id_{D_1\to D_2}
$$
In other words, yes.  Your method should work perfectly fine.